# Select in html with multiple select and javascript values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp-classic

am trying to do some AJAX work with classic asp and javascript.

my html code looks like this.

```
    <Select name="sName" multiple onchange="showMe(this.value)">
      <option value="000"></option>
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
      <option value="3">three</option>
      <option value="4">four</option>
    </Select
```

and my javascript looks like this

```
function showMe(sID) {
    var clID;
    if (sID == "") {
        document.getElementById("sDetails").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("sDetails").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "sList.asp?sID=" + sID + "&clID=" + clID, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

besides the above code i have a  called sDetails where the table gets populated.

my Problem is on multiple select.  this code takes only the last selected.

if i run sList.asp?sID=5,6&clID=10,103 the page gives me the desired result in tabular format.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: How do you identify the `select` elements when there's more than one?  If multiple elements have the same `id` (`"sDetails"`) then that's invalid markup and the behavior of `getElementById` is undefined.  `id` values need to be unique.

Comment: i have a div called sDetails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
function showMe(t) {
    var a = [];
    for ( var i = 0, l = t.options.length; i < l; i++ ) {
      var o = t.options[i];
      if (o.selected) {
        a.push(o.value);
      }
    }    
    var sID = a.length ? a.join(',') : 0;
    alert (sID);
}
</script>

<form name="selectTest"> <!-- optional -->
<select name="sName"multiple onchange="showMe(this)">
    <option value="000"></option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DMkJ8/)

P.S. Of course you need to accommodate this into your code to get it all working.

Comment: this does not work with my code.  I tried this.  added a alert(t) in the ShowMe and in my page i pasted your Select along with my Select.  now when i run the page and select my select which populates from the DB, i get the first alert with the correct ID, and no more alerts. but if i choose your Select then i get first alert as [Object HtmlSelectElement], and second alert as the ID.

Comment: and I must also point out, multiple select does work with the new combo, but not with my existing combo box.